# How to post-process JSON response in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am building an API with express and JSON middleware. I want to have a generic middleware that wraps each JSON response. The wrapping is an asynchronous process - there is a backend process that asynchronously generates a signature for the given JSON object. Example:

A route:

```js
app.use("/", (req, res) => res.json({status: "ok"}))
```

The middleware would ideally intercept the JSON response, asynchronously generate a signature and ultimately send the user the following JSON:

```
{
    "signature": "...",
    "content": { "status": "ok" }
}
```

**What's the best approach to building such a middleware?**

I have tried replacing res.json with a custom function. The problem with this solution is that the signature generation is asynchronous, but the res.json is a synchronous function. This was my approach:

```js
export function signatureMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    var json = res.json;
    res.json = async function (obj) {
      json.call(this, await wrapAndSign(obj));
    };
    next();
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with this approach? Most middleware (e.g. all body parsers) is async. _"What's the best approach to building such a middleware?"_ is opinion-based

Comment: If my route calls `res.json(...)` I am not sure it will wait for my async custom json method to complete in all situations. Or if a response will be sent before my signature call is completed. Just want to make sure it always works as expected

Comment: The response is sent by `json.call`, _after_ the `await wrapAndSign(obj)` has completed. So this should work.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I see three different questions, and I'm not sure what type of answer you expect. You answered the question in the title yourself with the code snippets. The answer to the question in the description is opinion-based without any metric for good. The answer to the implicit question in your comment is: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: @RomanSemko i have the exact same issue, how did you solve this at the end? Did you just ts-expect-error or ts-ignored the issue?